Difference of two holomorphic connections
I was reading Huybrechts' Complex Geometry: an introduction and came across some trouble involving the notion of holomorphic connection. I am trying to understand why it is claimed in page 179, shortly after Definition 4.2.17, that the difference of two holomorphic connections is a holomorphic section of $\Omega_X\otimes \text{End}(E)$. The explanation given is that the argument for ordinary "smooth" connections works also here with suitable modifications, so I would say that the difference of the two connections being $\mathcal{O}$-linear should imply our claim.
However, this is how I understand the argument works in the smooth case, and why I find an obstruction to carry it to the holomorphic setting. We first observe that the difference of our two connections is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$-linear, so it lies in $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^\infty(X)}(\mathcal{A}^0(X,E),\mathcal{A}^1(X,E))$. On the other hand, an element $a\in\mathcal{A}^1(X,\text{End}(E))$, that is, a global section of $\Lambda^1_\mathbb{C}X\otimes\text{End}(E)$, acts on smooth sections of $E$ by "evaluating", i.e. if $a=\sum \alpha\otimes F$, then $a(s):=\sum\alpha\otimes F(s)\in\mathcal{A}^1(X,E)$, for $s\in\mathcal{A}^0(E)$. Huybrechts' argument stops here, so what I understood at first is that we conclude because we just constructed a map $\mathcal{A}^1(X,\text{End}(E))\xrightarrow{}\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^\infty(X)}(\mathcal{A}^0(X,E),\mathcal{A}^1(X,E))$. Now, I am able to show that this map is bijective using bump functions, so we may identify its source and target to yield our claim.
My problem is that I don't think at all that this map is surjective in the holomorphic case, because bump functions are never holomorphic. So, how can we still say that the difference of the two connections is a holomorphic section of $\Omega_X\otimes\text{End}(E)$?
Furthermore, I would greatly appreciate some textbook which treats holomorphic connections. As far as I've been able to see, Huybrechts' book introduces them with few details, and all other textbooks I know (Voisin, Lee, Demailly, Kobayashi...) do not seem to mention the concept.

The difference of two holomorphic connections is an $ \mathcal{O}_X $-linear morphism from $ E $ to $ \Omega_X \otimes E $, hence is equivalently a section of $ \Omega_X \otimes E \otimes E^{\vee} = \Omega_X \otimes \operatorname{End} E $
